# Removing rows from result set where column only has one value against a user

Tags: sql

I have a result set

```
name stage  value
---- -----  -----
jim      1      4
jim      1      8
paul     1      8
paul     1      8
```

want to remove the rows where 8 is the only value against a person

- keep the 2 jim rows and lose the 2 paul rows

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`.  For a `select` query:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.value = 8
                 );
```

Similar logic (except using `exists` rather than `not exists`) can be used for a `delete` -- if you really want to delete the rows from the table.

If you have a complex query that you don't want to repeat, then window functions are helpful:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when value = 8 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name) as cnt_8
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_8 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database support analytical function then you can use count as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       Count(case when value <> 8 then 1 end) over (partition by name) as cnt
  From your_table t) t
Where cnt > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also have an ID column (defined as an auto increment integer) defined in your table this query would select the row with the highest id for each unique combination:

```
select max(id) from t group by name,stage,value
```

In your example this would only return the latest id for rows having values paul,1,8 in columns name,stage,value respectively.

You can then use the prior query to filter out any duplciates using it in the where clause:

```
select * from t
where id in (select max(id) from t group by name,stage,value)
```

Finally you can also delete rows that are not unique if that's your goal:

```
delete from t
where not id in (select max(id) from t group by name,stage,value)
```